# Convert Timespan - Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

The below code works. The last line formats the code as dd:hh:mm. How can I get it just to show as hh:mm. If I change the last line to

```
e.Row.Cells[4].Text = timeSpent.ToString(@"hh\:mm");
```

I get an exception as it goes over 24hrs. The aim is to get the output as 26:30 instead of 01:02:30

My code is:

```
    TimeSpan timeSpent = TimeSpan.Zero;

protected void GridViewFortNight_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
            {
                var tempTimeCalc = "";

                if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                {
                    tempTimeCalc = e.Row.Cells[4].Text.ToString();

                    timeSpent += TimeSpan.Parse(tempTimeCalc);


                }
                else if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
                {

                    e.Row.Cells[4].Text = timeSpent.ToString(@"dd\:hh\:mm");

                }


            }
```

Comment: Since you want to pass the 24 hours I will guess that you are trying to accumulate the time that has passed since and event or something like that. Could you tell me what you want to achieve exactly? Why do you need to go over 24 hours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not supported by the built-in format strings. You'll have to go a bit deeper and do some of the formatting yourself. It's not that bad, though:

```
e.Row.Cells[4].Text = string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}", (int)timeSpent.TotalHours, timeSpent.Minutes);
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked :) Please can you give a short explanation on the formatting used. Thanks

Comment: Here are the String.Format docs: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx   and here are the Custom Numeric Format String docs: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

you can do

```
   string s =
       $"{((int)timeSpent.TotalHours).ToString("00")}:{timeSpent.Minutes.ToString("00")}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add dataformatstring="{0:M-dd-yyyy}" attribute to the bound field, like this

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Date" HeaderText="Date" DataFormatString="{0:dd-M-yyyy}" />
```